# Docker, dangling container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

I cant start my docker-compose environment, because the port is allocated by something.

```
ERROR: for ***** Cannot start service *****: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint ***** (4314ec13837d41ca8ef1b7e1d8446ab8cfa96136539a75ac763ba1cf538ffdc1): Bind for 0.0.0.0:8881 failed: port is already allocated
Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

However, there is not such a container

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

But when I inspect the docker-compose network, I can see a container in the network

```
$ docker network inspect *****
[
    {
        "Name": "*****",
        "Id": "56d09f51e8fe5a9ad11dd6cdaff7e89983f519fd1ecff08116c2e48a3b34ff32",
        "Created": "2018-08-01T08:17:30.704352821Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "08a5defa5ceae7a5a5ac7ec85f5ecd0924ecb4e5eacca4f5752049e32a0f190c": {
                "Name": "08a5defa5cea_*****",
                "EndpointID": "5d081a19b5ffe4e893965a4306668059900812532cc4995e168ce017f2765e12",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:06",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.6/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "*****",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "docker"
        }
    }
]
```

Yet it is impossible to remove this container

```
docker rm -f *****
Error: No such container: *****
```

How to proceed?

Comment: do you have another service that runs on `8881`?

Comment: No, but restarting the docker-machine solved the problem. This is probably a docker bug.

Comment: or you could've try `docker network disconnect containerId`

Answer (score 0):

I run this script to shut down all stuck containers which sometimes linger

```
#!/bin/bash

# ... bring down all containers

force_it=""  #  normal
# force_it=" -f "  #  when you see  "device or resource busy"

for curr_container_id in $( docker ps -q ); do

    echo curr_container_id $curr_container_id
    echo
    echo "docker stop $curr_container_id "
          docker stop $curr_container_id
    echo
    echo "docker rm $force_it $curr_container_id "
          docker rm $force_it $curr_container_id
done

for curr_container_id in $( docker ps -q -a ); do

    echo curr_container_id $curr_container_id
    echo
    echo "docker stop $curr_container_id "
          docker stop $curr_container_id
    echo
    echo "docker rm $force_it $curr_container_id "
          docker rm $force_it $curr_container_id
done
```

it works 99% of the time ... if not near the top you can toggle the force parm and re-run it ... this allows you to avoid having to bounce any docker server